# i want take value from url

Tags: php, jquery

i have light box and have php loop like this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($something))
{
    echo '<a href="?id='.$row->id.'">'.$row->id.'</a>';
}
```

i want when click in link light box appear and contain 
from mysql where id value 
but the link does not change to take value with POST in php 
any idea

Comment: what does var_dump($row) say?

Comment: what is the errors you are having ?

Answer (score 0):

Place the content of lighbox in a PHP file.

Send an Ajax request to fetch the

Display response text in the lighbox div